# Is the meta tag content value from an xpath query trustable?

Tags: php, xpath

I have a php function who extracts meta tags from an url with xpath queries.

e.g `$xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="my_target"]/@content')`

My question :

Can I trust the returned value or should I verify it ?

=> Is there any possible XSS exploit ?

=> Should the html content be purified before loading it in the `DOMDocument` ?

```
 // Other way to say it with some code :

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    // is
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
    // trustable ??

    // or is
    file_get_contents($url);
    $trust = $purifier->purify($html);
    $doc->loadHTML($trust);
    // a better practice ??

    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $trustable = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[@name="my_target"]/@content')->item(0) // ?
```

===== UPDATE =========================================

Yes, never trust external sources.

use `$be_sure = htmlspecialchars($trustable->textContent)` or `strip_tags($trustable->textContent)`

Comment: We don't know if you trust the source of your HTML or not.

Comment: @Quentin This this the point I don't either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pull in HTML content from a source that you don't control, then yes, I would consider that piece of code potentially troublesome!

You could use [htmlspecialchars()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert any special characters to HTML entities. Or if you want to keep parts of the mark-up, you could use [strip_tags()](https://php.net/strip_tags). An other option is to use [filter_var()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) which gives you more control over its filtering.

Or you could use a library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) but that might be too much for your end. It all depends on the type of content you are working with.

Now, to sanitise the element, you will need to get the string representation of your XPath result first. Apply your filtering and then put it back in. The following example should do what you want:

```
<?php
// The following HTML is what you fetch from your remote source:
$html = <<<EOL
<html>
 <body>
    <h1>Foo, bar!</h1>
    <div id="my-target">
        Here is some <strong>text</strong> <script>javascript:alert('some malicious script!');</script> that we want to sanitize.
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
EOL;

// We instantiate a DOCDocument so we can work with it:
$original = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
$original->formatOutput = true;
$original->loadHTML($html);

$body = $original->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

// Find the element we need using Xpath:
$xpath = new DOMXPath($original);
$divs  = $xpath->query("//body/div[@id='my-target']");

// The XPath query will return DOMElement objects, so create a string that we can manipulate out of it:
$innerHTML  = '';
if (count($divs))
{
    $div = $divs->item(0);

    // Now get the innerHTML for this element
    foreach ($div->childNodes as $child) {
        $innerHTML .= $original->saveXML($child);
    }

    // Remove it from the original document because we want to replace it anyway
    $div->parentNode->removeChild($div);
}

// Sanitize our string by removing all tags except <strong> and the container <div>
$innerHTML = strip_tags($innerHTML, '<strong>');
// or htmlspecialchars() or filter_var or HTML Purifier ..

// Now re-import the sanitized string into a blank DOMDocument
$sanitized = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
$sanitized->formatOutput = true;
$sanitized->loadXML('<div id="my-target">' . $innerHTML . '</div>');

// Now add the sanitized DOMElement back into the original document as a child of <body>
$body->appendChild($original->importNode($sanitized->documentElement, true));

echo $original->saveHTML();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My example show a way to purify my content already (indeed `$purifier` is a reference to a tool as HTMLPurifier). Question is, is this a better practice to purify html just for a meta tag content ?

Comment: A HTML document will be perfectly safe to put into `DOMdocument` first, there's no way it might run PHP code. `DOMDocument` just parses a string. Even if there's a XSS exploit in there, it will only be executed when you output it to the browser.


For the contents of a meta tag I would definitely not go with a solution as HTMLPurifier as that's a pretty heavy library. Load it first with `DOMdocument`, then extract the meta tag contents and sanitise with  `htmlspecialchars` and/or `strip_tags`.